# You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. After deployed react app to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am newbie to react and made a portfolio on it and when I run it on local server, it works perfectly but after deploying to firebase by following this link `https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-firebase-hosting-98063c5bf425`, it is showing blank page and in console body "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." . What should be done? What files should I share? Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks !

Here is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BaseProvider, LightTheme } from "baseui";
import { Provider as StyletronProvider } from "styletron-react";
import { Client as Styletron } from "styletron-engine-atomic";


import "./index.css";
// import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "./assests/font-awesome/css/all.css";

const engine = new Styletron();

ReactDOM.render(
    <StyletronProvider value={engine}>
        <BaseProvider theme={LightTheme}>
                <App />
    </BaseProvider>
    </StyletronProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score -3):

You should enable javascript in your browser, see bellow how.

- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en-uk)
- [Safari](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/safari)
- [Firefox](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/firefox)
- [Edge](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/edge)

Comment: it's enabled in every browser, Problem is in the project somewhere

Comment: the no script code is in index.html in public folder, take a look there then

Comment: It was homepage value issue in package.json. Thanks though !